# Adding "ubuntu" user to Vagrant ubuntu instance

Tags: shell, useradd

I am using a vagrant box :

```
uname -a
Linux precise64 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64
```

It does not have `ubuntu` user setup , instead it has `vagrant` one ,so I decided to add new user and setup a ssh key for login as follow:

```
   sudo useradd ubuntu
   ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f ubuntu -t dsa     
   sudo mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/.ssh
   cat ubuntu.pub | sudo tee -a /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys  
   sudo chmod 600 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
   sudo chmod 700 /home/ubuntu/.ssh
   sudo chown -R ubuntu /home/ubuntu
```

Downloaded the private key and logged in. Now the terminal does not have any support for history e.g

```
history   
-sh: 30: history: not found
```

And none of the navigation keys are supported (up/down/forward/backward). I would like to setup bash to remember command line history as well as auto-completion for command and paths. Please let me know where I should start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your shell is not being bash but plain sh.

Super quick solution: just execute `bash` and see if that helps.

For a better and permanent solution please check /etc/passwd and see what shell does the user have there. If you find `/bin/sh` change it for `/bin/bash`

Comment: thank, I followed as you suggested and now working like charm

Answer (score 4):

The problem is indeed what @LuisAntolin pointed out. On Ubuntu systems, and most others, the default shell is `/bin/sh`. This is a symlink to `/bin/dash` on Debian-based systems. `dash` has no history command which is why you're getting that error.

While you can indeed change this by editing `/etc/password`, a better way is to run `chsh` as the user `ubuntu` and set the default shell to `/bin/bash`.

This is why `useradd` is deprecated in favor of `adduser`, a frontend to `useradd`, which is the recommended tool to use when creating a new user. From `man useradd`:

```
   useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian,
   administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.
```

So, next time, just use `adduser` and avoid this type of problem.